# Align chemical equation with potential

Tags: equations, align, siunitx

I want to make numbered chemical equation with the potential of that equation on the right. This is what I have:

```
\begin{align}
\label{eq:NiOOH}
    \ce{NiOOH + H2O + e- &<=>[discharge][charge] Ni(OH)2 + OH-}
    \tagaddtext{[$E_0,red=0,52$ \si{\volt}]}
\end{align}
```

For most of the equations this work, however if equation is too long it overlapse with potential:
[image]

I tried to align equation to the left with FLALIGN, but there was no change.

All other complex equations looks the same:
[image]

Comment: Can you share an image of the faulty output, including your attempts to fix the problem? It would be helpful to have a sense of where the overlap happens and why your previous attempt hasn't been successful

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usechemmodule{reactions}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{reaction}
    NiOOH + H2O + e- <=>[discharge][charge] Ni(OH)2 + OH-
     $\qquad[E_0,red=\SI{0,52}{\volt}]$ \label{rct:NiOOH}
\end{reaction}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is it standard to have the space between the equation and the potential be a fixed ```\qquad```-width, rather floating the partial right against the equation number, as in the original question? I would have thought floating would be preferable (but I am not a chemist)

Comment: Somehow, mine LaTeX template is not recognizing chemmacros package despite its declared in main tex file. It doesnt do that with other packages.
Also I probably can't use this kind of numbering in my thesis.

Comment: @Kamil: There was a small error in the previous version of the code. You might want to try again with the updated version. Regarding: "Also I probably can't use this kind of numbering" If you refer to the number being enclosed in a set of curly brackets, please keep in mind that you can change tat. `\chemsetup[reactions]{tag-open = [ ,tag-close = ]}` for example results in square brackets instead.

Answer (score 1):

I propose this MWE and I have get this using for the double arrow `chemarrow` package. Of course you can always use the specific `chemmacros` package. For the use of `\tagaddtext`
from this [site](https://www.latex4technics.com/?note=3duo), you must add the code:

```
\makeatletter
\providecommand\add@text{}
\newcommand\tagaddtext[1]{%
  \gdef\add@text{#1\gdef\add@text{}}}% 
\renewcommand\tagform@[1]{%
  \maketag@@@{\llap{\add@text\quad}(\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr)}%
}
\makeatother
```

---

It is very important that you add a minimal complete compilable code.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{chemarrow}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{detect-all}

\makeatletter
\providecommand\add@text{}
\newcommand\tagaddtext[1]{%
  \gdef\add@text{#1\gdef\add@text{}}}% 
\renewcommand\tagform@[1]{%
  \maketag@@@{\llap{\add@text\quad}(\ignorespaces#1\unskip\@@italiccorr)}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\mathrm{NiOOH + H_2O + e^-} \autorightleftharpoons{discharge}{charge} \mathrm{Ni(OH)_2 + OH^-}& &\tagaddtext{$[E_0, \text{red}=0.52 \si{\volt}]$}
\label{eq:NiOOH}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This does work for this particular equation, however I do have more complex ones and it doesnt work for those. Is there a way how to make text in equations smaller? \small or \tiny does not work as it do for tables.

Comment: @Kamil If you prefer I delete my answer. You can use in math mode or \scriptstyle or \scriptscriptstyle. \small or \tiny are specific only for the text.

Comment: No, let it here. It is a pretty good answer. You helped me at least with arrows, this way it looks better.

Comment: i will only replace `\text{red}=0.52 \si{\volt}` with `\text{red}=\SI{0.52}{\volt}`. (+1)

Comment: @Zarko Kindest Zarko you know you are authorized to do whatever you want in my answers...:-) You can improved my answer. :-)